# How can i get internal storage and not sd card in android?

Tags: java, android

I know how to get the external storage we use:

```
String file = Enviroment.getExternalStorageDir();
```

Now I want to write my files on phone storage by using `FileWriter` and `DataOutputStream`.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
```

This is used to get files from both external and interal storage in device